# JS dates and jQuery UI slider being strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui

I am creating a range slider in jQuery UI that has a certain date (2013-12-3) to today's date.

I need to range to be able to select every single date between these two.

However whenever I try to change the date using my slider it behaves very strangely.

I am using the slider to select days and then creating the new dates by adding them onto the start date.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var startDate = new Date(2013, 12, 3);
 var endDate = new Date();
 var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
 var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
 
 var fromDate = new Date(2013, 12, 3);
 var toDate = new Date();
 
 $("#rangeSlider").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: diffDays,
  animate: true,
  slide: function (event, ui) {
   fromDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + ui.values[0]);
   toDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + ui.values[1]);
   
   $("#rangeFromDate").html(fromDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + fromDate.getDate());
   $("#rangeToDate").html(toDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (toDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + toDate.getDate());
  }
 }); 
});
```

```css
#rangeSlider {
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
#rangeFrom {
 float: left;
}
#rangeTo {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<div id="rangeSlider"></div>

<span id="rangeFrom">From: <span id="rangeFromDate">2013-12-3</span></span>
<span id="rangeTo">To: <span id="rangeToDate">2016-12-12</span></span>
```

**EDIT:** I need the dates to be shown in ISO format and I need the dual handles on my slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use local variable for `fromDate` and `toDate` to reintialize each time. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/4yd7s4gt/#&togetherjs=3a0uuNweqJ)

**JS:**

```
var startDate = new Date(2013, 12, 3);
            var endDate = new Date();
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            $("#rangeSlider").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: diffDays,
                step: 1,
                animate: true,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    var fromDate = new Date(2013, 12, 3);
                    var toDate = new Date();
                    fromDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + parseInt(ui.values[0]));
                    toDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + parseInt(ui.values[1]));

                    $("#rangeFromDate").text(fromDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (fromDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + fromDate.getDate());
                    $("#rangeToDate").text(toDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (toDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + toDate.getDate());
                }
            });
```

Comment: I literally just did that going off of dpp's answer and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Added in a Selected Date Input:

```
<span id="rangeFrom">From: <span id="rangeFromDate">2013-12-3</span></span>
<span id="rangeTo">To: <span id="rangeToDate">2016-12-12</span></span>
<!--- SHOW DATE HERE -->
<p>
  <label for="amount">Selected Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" placeholder="Not Selected">
</p>
```

In the JQueryUI, set our max range and calculates by taking base date and adding days, difference already calculated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //months start at 0, so 11 is Dec, not 12
  //DEFINE YOUR START AND END DATE RANGE
  //TAKES START DATE AND END DATE CALCULATES DAYS
  //IN BETWEEN TO SET THE MAX, 
  //SLIDER THEN INCREMENTS BY DAYS
    var startDate = new Date(2013, 11, 3);
    var endDate = new Date(2016,11,12);

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    $("#rangeSlider").slider({
    //set our ranges here, min to max days, calculated above
    //with diffdays
    //MIN AND MAX ARE DAYS! SO min 0 is 0 DAYS from the start date
    //MAX IS  #of days between start and end so start date + max days =
    //END DATE
        range: "max",
        min: 0,
        max: diffDays,
        animate: true,

       slide: function (event, ui) {
         //set our starting point to add days to it.
         //max is taken care of above in max: diffdays
         var result = new Date(2013, 11, 3);
         result.setDate(result.getDate() + ui.value);
         //format the date
         var isoDate = result.getFullYear() + "-" + (result.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + result.getDate();
         //set the amount field
         $( "#amount" ).val(isoDate);
      }
   });  
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkugtmq4/)

Comment: I need to have the range so that I can select a time frame. I also want the date in ISO format for later use

Comment: Your range is your start and end date. Just format the date, 
    var isoDate = result.getFullYear() + "-" + (result.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + result.getDate();
      //set the amount field
      $( "#amount" ).val(isoDate);

to get what you want it to be.